# Most lightweight cross-platform http python host

Tags: python, windows, uwsgi

We've got a couple of quite complex sites written in Python based on Django, hosted by uwsgi. We also use nginx for some out-of-application things (like SSL termination).

I need to write an incredibly lightweight API which does nothing except validate an authentication token (against a different API) and respond with some info from the local file system.

I'd prefer to avoid using a whole Django site for what will be ~50 lines of code, however, since I develop on a windows machine, I'm not sure how best to host this tiny API for dev/testing. (Django's `runserver` command usually handles this for us) uWSGI seems like a good choice for final usage as it's already in use elsewhere but doesn't run on Windows.

I could always just code on one box, deploy and then test but it seems a little long-winded. Ideally, whatever I can find to host on windows will call my code in the same way as uwsgi

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most lightweight would be [`wsgiref.simple_server`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) from the standard library which Django's `runserver` command [uses](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4ff682c1ba1cd051243842bbd2feb19e75b559f3/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L4) internally.

Alternatively you can use

- [WSGI server](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/httpserver.html?highlight=httpserver#module-paste.httpserver) from the Paste

> This is a minimalistic WSGI server using Python’s built-in
>   BaseHTTPServer; if pyOpenSSL is installed, it also provides SSL
>   capabilities.

- [Waitress](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) from the Pylons project

> Waitress is meant to be a production-quality pure-Python WSGI server
>   with very acceptable performance. **It has no dependencies except ones
>   which live in the Python standard library**. It runs on CPython on
>   Unix and **Windows** under Python 2.6+ and Python 3.2+. It is also
>   known to run on PyPy 1.6.0 on UNIX. It supports HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1.

- [WSGI server](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/wsgiserver/init.html) from CherryPy

> A high-speed, production ready, thread pooled, generic HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, that looks like exactly what I was after. I think I might take a page out of Django's book and go with the simple_server.